# Pygame colliderect causing issues with ball game

Tags: python, pygame, collision-detection

I am making a putt putt game. I made the walls and the balls with classes and each class has a rect defining its position. All of the walls are in a list and I check the list using colliderect to see if the ball is hitting any of the walls. If so, depending on the wall (vertical or horizontal), I change the direction the ball is going. The problem is that occasionally, the ball will hit the wall and get stuck inside. I imagine that it is just continually colliding with the wall and keeps changing direction, making it just stay still.

Ive tried adding a cooldown, but even that doesn't always work. The speed of the ball shouldn't be the issue as if it moves 3px per frame, if would be moving that same speed out on the next frame after its direction was changed. However, slower speeds help but still dont completely solve this issue. Also, I am detection collisions before I move the ball on each frame.

```
for wall in walls:
    if wall.type == "hwall":
        if wall.rect.colliderect(ball.rect):
            ball.y_change = -(ball.y_change)
    elif wall.type == "vwall":
        if wall.rect.colliderect(ball.rect):
            ball.x_change = -(ball.x_change)
```

Here is the full code:
https://pastebin.com/85Ge175i

Comment: if ball colides with wall then move ball a little back so it will only touch wall - if it moves left then `ball.rect.left = wall.rect.right` , if it moves right then `ball.rect.right = wall.rect.left`

Comment: with `Sprite.Group()` you could check collisin with all walls at once without `for` loop. And there is method that first move ball only on X and check with all walls (and eventually move it little back), next you move ball only on Y and check it with all walls again (and eventually move it little back). This way you can resolves some problems - ie. if you stuck in corner.

Comment: in [example](http://programarcadegames.com/python_examples/show_file.php?file=move_with_walls_example.py) you can see this method in `update()`.

Comment: @furas This makes a lot of sense and everything tells me it should work, but I still get stuck in walls. Could it be something to do with how fast the ball goes or how fast I run the program?

Comment: it doesn't matter how fast program run. Problem is how far into wall moves ball. When part of ball is inside wall then you have to move it back so it only touch wall - one or zero pixels.  ie. `ball.rect.left = wall.rect.right`

Comment: @furas I move it more than enough to get out of the wall and switch its direction, and somehow it still gets stuck in the wall. I move it more than double how far it can possibly go in and it still happens

Comment: maybe you move in one direction but it is still collision in another direction. You can use `print()` to see values in variables and which brick in the wall makes problem.

Comment: there is no sense to try resolve it without code. We can't guess what is the problem.

Comment: @furas I am editing and adding a link to the full code. I tried to comment it best as I can but let me know if your confused. Its probably not the cleanest or best code.

Comment: I checked code. You have problem because you have ball's position in two places: `(ball.x,ball.y)` and `(ball.rect.x, ball.rect.y)`. First you move ball `ball.x += ball.y_change` but later you check collision using old position in `ball.rect`. You should use only `ball.rect` - `ball.rect.x += ball.y_change` and then it works correctly, almost ideal. If you slow down to `clock.tick(10)` then you can see that ball doesn't go inside wall. Sometimes it doesn't touch wall but it is problem for `ball.rect.left = wall.rect.right`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tried all methods suggested and none worked for me. Gave up on using the pygame colliderect feature as it doesnt seem to work for my specific needs. Instead I checked the ball position with all walls and manual got collision that way. Also upon collision I move the ball back a bit to prevent it getting stuck in walls.

```
# Check for collision
for wall in walls:
    if wall.type == "hwall":

        if ball.y_change < 0:
            if wall.rect.top <= ball.rect.top <= wall.rect.bottom and wall.rect.left <= ball.rect.center[0] <= wall.rect.right:
                ball.y_change = -(ball.y_change)
                ball.y += speed_y * 2
        else:
            if wall.rect.top <= ball.rect.bottom <= wall.rect.bottom and wall.rect.left <= ball.rect.center[0] <= wall.rect.right:
                ball.y_change = -(ball.y_change)
                ball.y -= speed_y * 2


    elif wall.type == "vwall":

        if ball.x_change < 0:
            if wall.rect.left <= ball.rect.left <= wall.rect.right and wall.rect.top <= ball.rect.center[1] <= wall.rect.bottom:
                ball.x_change = -(ball.x_change)
                ball.x += speed_x * 2
        else:
            if wall.rect.left <= ball.rect.right <= wall.rect.right and wall.rect.top <= ball.rect.center[1] <= wall.rect.bottom:
                ball.x_change = -(ball.x_change)
                ball.x -= speed_x * 2
```

Answer (score 1):

A quick solution could be to check not only for collisions, but also the position of the edges of the rectangles of walls and ball.
The code should be self explanatory:

```
for wall in walls:
    if wall.rect.colliderect(ball.rect):
        if wall.type == "hwall" and wall.rect.bottom < ball.rect.bottom and ball.y_change > 0:
            ball.y_change = -(ball.y_change)
        elif wall.type == "hwall" and wall.rect.top > ball.rect.top and ball.y_change < 0:
            ball.y_change = -(ball.y_change)
        elif wall.type == "vwall" and wall.rect.right < ball.rect.right and ball.x_change > 0:
            ball.x_change = -(ball.x_change)
        elif wall.type == "vwall" and wall.rect.left > ball.rect.left and ball.x_change < 0:
            ball.x_change = -(ball.x_change)
```

This way you are sure that once the velocity component is flipped, it's not flipped back immediately.